# combining two arrays in specific format

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to combine two arrays into one in a specific format. Please guide me on how i can achieve this.

```
let arr = [{'test' : 1}, {'test1' : 2}, {'test2': 3}, {'test3': 4}];
let arr1 = [{'testdo': 5}, {'testdo1': 6}, {'testdo2': 7}, {'testdo3': 8}];

// the resulted array should look like this.

arr3 = [{'test': 1}, {'testdo': 5}, {'test1': 2}, {'testdo1': 6}, {'test2': 3}, {'testdo2': 7},
       {'test3': 4}, {'testdo3': 8}];
```

I have tried this

```
 for(let i = 0; i<=6; i++){
     let arr3: any = [arr[i], arr1[i]];
     console.log(arr3);
  }
```

Comment: By `=` you mean using objects (`:`), correctly?

Comment: Note that you have syntax errors in your code. Please explain the logic behind the order of the elements in the array. Is it simply one from `arr`, one from `arr1`, one from `arr`, etc.? Please also show what attempts you've made at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: What happens if one array is shorter than the other?

Comment: I have arrays of equal length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work with arrays of any length.

```js
let arr = [{'test' : 1}, {'test1' : 2}, {'test2': 3}, {'test3': 4}];
let arr1 = [{'testdo': 5}, {'testdo1': 6}, {'testdo2': 7}, {'testdo3': 8}];

let arr3 = [];
let max = Math.max(arr.length, arr1.length);

for (let i=0; i < max; i++) {
  if (arr.length > i) {
    arr3.push(arr[i]);
  }
  if (arr1.length > i) {
    arr3.push(arr1[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need something like:

```
const arr = [{test: 1}, {test1: 2}, {test2: 3}, {test3: 4}];
const arr1 = [{testdo: 5}, {testdo1: 6}, {testdo2: 7}, {testdo3: 8}];

const arr3 = [...arr];
let offset = 0;

arr1.forEach((arr1Item, index) => {
  if (index <= arr?.length) {
    const targetIndex = index + 1 + offset;
    const removeCount = 0;

    arr3.splice(targetIndex, removeCount, arr1Item);

    offset += 1;
  } else {
    arr3.push(arr1Item);
  }
});
```

*arr3* now has the shape you probably need.

I hope this helps you.